# Missing google-services.json and run "make bootstrap" (Kickstarter app android studio)

Tags: bash, android-studio, bootstrap-4, git-bash, google-play-services

I encountered this google service missing error when I try to run the app [Kickstarter from GitHub](https://github.com/kickstarter/android-oss) in Android Studio.

Tried to look for answers and I found that I am supposed to run "make bootstrap" but I really can't quite understand how you do it (i'm still a novice in coding/android/github in general).

Here is the error:

`File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.
Searched Location:
C:\Users\naufa\AndroidStudioProjects\android-oss\app\src\external\min21\debug\google-services.json C:\Users\naufa\AndroidStudioProjects\android-oss\app\src\externalMin21\debug\google-services.json C:\Users\naufa\AndroidStudioProjects\android-oss\app\src\debug\externalMin21\google-services.json C:\Users\naufa\AndroidStudioProjects\android-oss\app\src\external\debug\google-services.json C:\Users\naufa\AndroidStudioProjects\android-oss\app\src\external\min21\google-services.json C:\Users\naufa\AndroidStudioProjects\android-oss\app\src\external\min21Debug\google-services.json C:\Users\naufa\AndroidStudioProjects\android-oss\app\src\externalMin21\google-services.json C:\Users\naufa\AndroidStudioProjects\android-oss\app\src\debug\google-services.json C:\Users\naufa\AndroidStudioProjects\android-oss\app\src\externalMin21Debug\google-services.json C:\Users\naufa\AndroidStudioProjects\android-oss\app\src\external\google-services.json C:\Users\naufa\AndroidStudioProjects\android-oss\app\src\externalDebug\google-services.json C:\Users\naufa\AndroidStudioProjects\android-oss\app\google-services.json`

The scenario was:

I imported the project into Android Studio, when I try to run the app, the error above pops up. I browsed for solutions and found out that I need to run "make bootstrap" in some sort of terminal/CMD, but I have zero ideas on how to do that, heck i don't even know what bootstrap is.

There was a lot of different answers that i have no idea how to do since the answers was meant for non-beginners. I'm so confused, some help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm running Windows 10 64-bit, if there is any other info I should provide please do tell me. Here's the Clone link if anyone would like to open it in Android Studio = https://github.com/kickstarter/android-oss.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Issue 36](https://github.com/kickstarter/android-oss/issues/36#issuecomment-273913411) does warn you:

> If you didn't donwload as a zip, make sure you run "make bootstrap" before opening the app within android studio.

So: clone the repo, do *not* open Android Studio, do *not* import it just yet.

Do the `make bootstrap` first in command line.
Once that is done, open Android Studio and import it.

On Windows 10, this is best done in a [WSL Linux shell](https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/), as advised in [`kickstarter/android-oss` issue 28](https://github.com/kickstarter/android-oss/issues/28#issuecomment-321996925).

Comment: yes but i'm not sure how do you "make bootstrap", do you use windows command prompt? do you need to change directory first? if yes, where?

and when i do try to write "make bootstrap" and press enter, it says 

`make is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

I am a complete novice on command line

Comment: would be really amazing if you could guide me, I'm really stuck here because unlike other problems I've encountered, there is little to no people having this same problem.

Comment: @NaufalAdi Since you are on Windows 10, use the WSL native bash: https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/, as mentioned in https://github.com/kickstarter/android-oss/issues/28#issuecomment-321996925

Comment: alright! i got it working, thanks a lot man. jeez i had to learn linux and stuff just to get to the real thing haha (btw sorry i still can't upvote your answer, still below rep 15)

Comment: oh, my bad haha