# How to " run make bootstrap" while opening Kickstarter source code

Tags: android, google-play-services

I encountered this google service missing error when I try to run the app Kickstarter from GitHub in Android Studio.

Tried to look for answers and I found that I am supposed to run "make bootstrap" but I really can't quite understand how you do it (I'm still a novice in coding/android/github in general).

Here is the error:

```
File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.
Searched Location:
C:\Users\naufa\AndroidStudioProjects\android-oss\app\src\external\min21\debug\google-services.json 
C:\Users\naufa\AndroidStudioProjects\android-oss\app\src\externalMin21\debug\google-services.json
C:\Users\naufa\AndroidStudioProjects\android-oss\app\src\debug\externalMin21\google-services.json
C:\Users\naufa\AndroidStudioProjects\android-oss\app\src\external\debug\google-services.json
C:\Users\naufa\AndroidStudioProjects\android-oss\app\src\external\min21\google-services.json
C:\Users\naufa\AndroidStudioProjects\android-oss\app\src\external\min21Debug\google-services.json
C:\Users\naufa\AndroidStudioProjects\android-oss\app\src\externalMin21\google-services.json
C:\Users\naufa\AndroidStudioProjects\android-oss\app\src\debug\google-services.json
C:\Users\naufa\AndroidStudioProjects\android-oss\app\src\externalMin21Debug\google-services.json
C:\Users\naufa\AndroidStudioProjects\android-oss\app\src\external\google-services.json
C:\Users\naufa\AndroidStudioProjects\android-oss\app\src\externalDebug\google-services.json
C:\Users\naufa\AndroidStudioProjects\android-oss\app\google-services.json
```

The scenario was:

I imported the project into Android Studio, when I try to run the app, the error above pops up. I browsed for solutions and found out that I need to run "make bootstrap" in some sort of terminal/CMD, but I have zero ideas on how to do that. I don't even know what a bootstrap is.

There was a lot of different answers that I have no idea how to do since the answers was meant for non-beginners. I'm so confused, some help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm running Windows 11 64-bit, if there is any other info I should provide please do tell me. Here's the Clone link if anyone would like to open it in Android Studio: https://github.com/kickstarter/android-oss.git

I know someone had the same problem but I just can't understand that answer/solution so it would be really helpful if someone can explain in easy words.

Comment: Hi @Lalit! Welcome to SO. "There was a lot of different answers" Please do link all the resources you came through while researching on your own, in the question itself. "I just can't understand that answer/solution" -> We need to know what you looked at before commenting :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52417735/19070132

Comment: This is the single/ best solution I had found same as mine other didn't even had this problem  so it is difficult to find an actual solution

Comment: https://github.com/kickstarter/android-oss/issues/28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap is a set of initial files required to build the project. Since you miss the "bootstrap" you get the error.

`make bootstrap` refers to a command that will build the needed files for you.

> [GNU Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) is a tool which controls the generation of executables and other non-source files of a program from the program's source files.

and `bootstrap` is a [step in the project's Makefile](https://github.com/kickstarter/android-oss/blob/master/Makefile#L4) that controls building the files for you. `make bootstrap` command basically asks the `make` software to run the `bootstrap` step from the Makefile.

From the issue thread it seems you can't do it directly from Windows. You need [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install) which is just linux bash for windows.

Once you install WSL, install make and ruby. Run these commands one by one:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ruby-full make
```

This should add `ruby` and `make`.

Then clone the kickstart project again (through WSL this time). `cd` into it (again through WSL) and run `make bootstrap`.

It will take a moment, once the bootstraps are built you can proceed to run AndroidStudio as usual.

That's what the issue thread on GitHub explains. I hope this made it simpler for you!

Comment: " Make bootstrap "do I just use this command like this ? And cd into it what does that mean ? (I am completely new in all this )

Comment: And I had to run all these ( Ruby , make and other ) commands in WSL ? - BTW THANK YOU SOOOO MUCH YOU MAKE IT A LOT LOT LOT EASIER I  am REALLY GREATFUL OF YOU

Comment: WSL is like cmd, when you install it you get a window where you can run commands.  After you install ruby and make, you can cd into the folder (cd means change directory, basically move into the folder where the project is) where you cloned the project. And type `make bootstrap` in the window and press enter. It will do the thing for you. Once done you can close wsl and open project in Android Studio. I did that and the app builds fine for me.

Comment: yes, install ruby and make in WSL, also run the `make bootstrap` in WSL. Rest all things are in normal Android Studio.

Comment: For cd can I just right click on the project folder (where I cloned it) and open wsl command because I know no other way of cd or if there are other can u tell ?

Comment: @Lalitsharma I am not sure if you can right click folder to open in wsl. But cd command is simple! Here are 2 basic commands you should know: `ls`(L and S)- lists the files and folders in current directory. `cd`- change directory.

Comment: If you type `cd folder` and there exists a folder named "folder", the terminal will move to that folder so all the commands that you type will be run in that folder then...

Comment: I highly recommend please learn about basics before moving into complex projects! Even if the project name is "kickstart" it doesn't seem so beginner friendly to be honest. Try learning from Google Beginner Codelabs here: https://developer.android.com/courses

Also do learn basic linux commands, will always be helpful!

Comment: Thank you brother I have understood it because of you & yeah I am learning basics as well thought I should work on a project on the side as well

Comment: make bootstrap
git submodule sync --recursive
Synchronizing submodule url for 'vendor/material-design-icons'
git submodule update --init --recursive || true
Cloning into '/home/lalit/android-oss/vendor/material-design-icons'...

Comment: brother i did everything but wsl is stuck here do i need to do something manually here?

Comment: @Lalitsharma even my m1 Mac was stuck for 5 minutes with 50mbps network speed. Expect windows to take atleast 7-10 minutes. It is downloading the repository which is huge. Depends on your network connection as well.